# Why setOnclick Button not working?

Tags: android

I use android 2.3.3 
my code:

```
    read=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_read);
    write=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_write);
    text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    // write file
    write.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
```

but when i click button Toast not show. can anybody tell me why? thanks

Comment: Please add your logcat and xml file

Comment: below answer's are correct if working accept any one answer!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add show method for showing Toast View

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

doesn't show Toast your code are like below

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

toast view for more details refer this document http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 0):

At the end of Toast you need to add ".show()".

Code:

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```